# How does local hosting work after a CI build on platforms like Jenkins for Github Actions?

Tags: jenkins, action, cicd

*New to CI/CD here:*

From what I understand, both Github Actions and Jenkins, at a very low level, are tools that build your code (that run tests, etc, or whatever you want, really). After this, I've seen that a common approach would be to push that code to a cloud platform, like AWS or Heroku.

How would one recreate the functionality of AWS/Heroku on a local VM?

Comment: Usually in CI code goes through pre commit check during CI once this is done the code goes through some quality check , then image is build and push to a container registry ,then we pull the image from a privet registry and deploy the application. This is the basic overview.

Comment: Thanks, so my question revolves around how you pull the image from that registry and deploy it; how does that work and what software is used?

Comment: There are many options this could be done using Jenkins declarative pipeline, Azure Devops release pipeline, GitHub actions workflow or you have the option to choose CD tools like Spinnaker or ArgoCd. I am assuming you are deploying the application on a Cloud. So you need to basically pull the image from container registry and deploy using the cloud providers cli command.